# wouldn't pwm cause uneven motor motion?

Tags: performance, pwm

I mean basically the PWM is causing the motor to run, stop, run, stop, run, stop at different intervals, wouldn't it make a very uneven ride>?

Comment: In what context? Under what circumstances? In fact, what are you talking about?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on Electronics.SE

Answer (score 1):

The PWM switching frequency is always so high that the inherent inertia of the load ensures a smooth behavior.

For example, for PWM-controlled computer fans, the PWM signal is around 25 kHz, while the fan rotates at 200 - 2000 RPM. No time for the fan to slow down between PWM pulses.

There are loads that can tolerate a slower signal: For an electric stove with big metal hotplates, a PWM frequency below 1 Hz (e.g. just few times a minute) is enough.

Comment: i am thinking more of a PWM controlled step motor, where the RPM may be low to archive higher torque, in that case, a digital PWM may have a frequency under 100Hz, would that not cause a problem? I heard that a sine wave may be more suitable than PWM in this type of application, but again, a sine wave also have the effect of pushing the motor gradually instead of a linear motion